# Get current console output in python

Tags: python, console, output

I want to get the current console output of my program in python. There are a lot of solutions to get the console output when running an external program, however, I couldn't find any solution for getting the console output of the current program. Am I missing something? I am looking for a solution which works under windows and linux.

For example:

```
print "Hello world"
output = get_console_output() # Returns "Hello World\n"
```

**Edit:**
The solution should preserve the console output, so just replacing stdout won't work, as the console will be empty then

Comment: Why do you need to do this, what are you trying to achieve?  You might wish to checkout `StringIO` in the standard library.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question: the console doesn't "generate output" it prints your output, so if you want your output save it in a string and only then print it. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding your question ?

Comment: I have a lot of print statements, and "save it in a string" would require me to change every print statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the output you need to redirect the standard output `stdout` somewhere. You can use `StringIO` for this for example:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys

sys.stdout = buffer = StringIO()

print "Hello World"

# get output via: buffer.getvalue()
```

If you rather want the output to a file you could instead redirect directly to a file:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'w')
print 'Hello World'
```

Edit: If you want output to be appended to log (according to comment), I suggest a custom class:

```
import sys

class Log(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.orgstdout = sys.stdout
        self.log = open("log.txt", "a")

    def write(self, msg):
        self.orgstdout.write(msg)
        self.log.write(msg)  

sys.stdout = Log()
print('Hello World')
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the output redirected to a file while still outputing to the console?

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite sys.stdout with any file-like object:

```
import sys
import StringIO
sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
```

You should also think about using the logging module instead of print. Or simply write a function that stores and prints values.