# Get current console output(sys.stdin) in python

Tags: python, console, output, stdin, sys

I want to get the current console output(sys.stdin) of my program in python. I found the answer for sys.stdout, however, I found out for the output caused by input() function it goes to sys.stdin stream.

For example,

```
input("Where are you from: ")
input_text = get_console_input() #"Where are you from: "
```

I tried this method([Get current console output in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422996/get-current-console-output-in-python/77847884#77847884)) by replacing sys.stdout to sys.stdin, but it caused "EOFError: EOF when reading a line"

Edit: The output from `input` function still can be found on standard output stream!

Comment: Your question is confusing.  "console output" would go to sys.stdout, not sys.stdin.  Why are you asking about sys.stdin?

Comment: `input` writes the prompt to standard output. It's not clear why you need to *retreive* that, since it's just the string that was passed to `input` in the first place.

Comment: @chepner does it really go to standard output? When I checked the standard output stream, nothing came out with `input` function. That's why I was checking other stream which was stdin

Comment: @JohnGordon What I mean by "console output" is that when you use `input` function with the parameter "where are you from: ", it will be printed out to console but when I check the sys.stdout, it does not have "where are you from: ", so that's why I suspected that it might be in sys.stdin.

Comment: _When I checked the standard output stream, nothing came out with input function_ Please show us the actual full code you tried, and the results of that code.

Comment: If (and there's a "but" coming, so keep reading) I run `python3 -c 'input("foo")' > out.txt 2> err.txt`, `foo` appears in `out.txt`, not `err.txt`. If I supply only an stdout redirection, the prompt appears there. **But**, if I supply only a stderr redirection, the prompt appears there as well. So I don't know *what* is going on.

Comment: I just tested with the isolated condition with only `input` function and saw it go to sys.stdout. Thank you for helping me out!